# Take a number and sum its digits raised to the consecutive powers

Tags: performance, functional-programming, scala

I am new to Scala have to solve this problem:

> If you have number "xy" should equal  sum of  consecutive powers of its digits
>
> xy = x^1 + y^2
>
> For example, take the number 89 and you should have:
>
> 89 = 8^1+ 9^2
>
> And if we have a list we should filter with the matched numbers based on the above role.
>
> For example:
>
> Consider these range of numbers:
>
> (1, 100) == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 89]
>
> (90, 100) == []

This code works fine, but is this a pure functional programming style or are there some best practices in terms of performance and functionality?

```
def myFun(str: String):Double ={

   val myDigits=str.toList.map(_.asDigit)

   (myDigits.indices zip myDigits).toMap.map({case(x , y) =>  pow(y,x+1)}).reduce(_+_)

}

(1 to 100 ) .toList.filter({ case(x) => x == myFun(x.toString) })
```

Comment: What does `17` have to do with anything?

Comment: @200_success you are right I have been edited it.

Comment: On an algorithmic note, maintaining an array

$$
\{0^n, 1^n,  2^n, \ldots, 9^n\}
$$

as you go along will be asymptotically more efficient than calling `pow` each iteration.

Answer (score 3):

**Recommendations:**

- For starters I would recommend passing an `Int` to your function and then converting it to a `String` before splitting it up and mapping it to its digit components.
- Next, Scala has a useful built in function called `zipWithIndex` that you could use over `(myDigits.indices zip myDigits)`. Granted it will reverse the ordering from what you have, but that can be handled as you can see in the code below.
- I would also recommend splitting any map / filter / etc over multiple lines to increase readability.
- When you are using `reduce` to sum the elements of a container you can instead apply the built in `sum` method.
- Finally, I would hold off on converting the `(1 to 100)` from a `Range` to a `List` until after your `filter` operation is complete.

**Code:**

```
def f(i: Int): Int ={
  val myDigits = i.toString.map(_.asDigit)

  myDigits.zipWithIndex.map { case (y, x) =>
    pow(y, x+1).toInt
  }.sum
}

val x = (1 to 100).filter(i => i == f(i)).toList
```